# PHP Modify Json value with form data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to replace values from a json file with values submitted from a form.
Json file is as following:

```
{
    "meta_titles": {
        "Just another site": "",
        "Test test": "",
        "This is a test post": "",
        "Hello world!": ""
    },
    "tag_titles": {
        "Title Test": "",
        "Recent Posts": "",
        "Recent Comments": "",
    }
}
```

And PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [meta_titles-0] => Juste un autre site Wordpress
    [meta_titles-1] => 
    [meta_titles-2] => Ceci est un test post
    [meta_titles-3] => Salut le monde
    [tag_titles-0] => 
    [tag_titles-1] => 
    [tag_titles-2] => 
)
```

Should return:

```
{
    "meta_titles": {
        "Just another site": "Juste un autre site Wordpress",
        "Test test": "",
        "This is a test post": "Ceci est un test post",
        "Hello world!": "Salut le monde"
    },
    "tag_titles": {
        "Title Test": "",
        "Recent Posts": "",
        "Recent Comments": "",
    }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
         $filecontent = file_get_contents($website_directory.'/'.$file_to_read);
         $oJson = json_decode($filecontent, true);

         foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            foreach($oJson->fields as $i => $oVal) {
                    $oJson->fields[$i]->value = $val;
            }
         }
         $json = json_encode($oJson);
         var_dump($json);
```

Tried a lot of things but didn't find a way to do it.
EDIT: I get the exact same content of the json file from var_dump.

Comment: What did you get from `var_dump($json);` ?

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski I get the exact same content of the json file from var_dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Second param from `json_decode` if set to `true` mean that `$oJson` will be `array`. So you will access `$oJson` like an `array`.
- Your have to get the number from php array and search in json what key is at that position and update that key in the array. In json you have multi-level array and in `$_POST` you have only single level array.

You have to change to:

```
     $filecontent = file_get_contents($website_directory.'/'.$file_to_read);
     $oJson = json_decode($filecontent, true);

     foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        list($json_key, $json_no) = explode("-", $key);
        $json_keys = array_keys($oJson[$json_key]);
        $oJson[$json_key][$json_keys[$json_no]] = $val;
     }
     $json = json_encode($oJson);
     var_dump($json);
```

Comment: Damn Daniel!! Back at it again with the right answer! Thanks a lot, working perfectly like I want!